# "Error isar_flutter_libs: ^3.0.5", how to fix this issue?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-isar

I have embeded flutter in my iOS app using add to app method.
I have added isar library which is causing iOS pipeline to fail in fast lane step.
iOS build pipeline is failing with below error:

error :

ld: could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1400.0.29.102.0_0' Reader: '1300.0.29.30_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 13.0.0, (clang-1300.0.29.30)' for architecture arm64[12:32:49]:

▸ ❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Xcode version : 13.2.1
Flutter Version : 3.3.10
Isar Version : 3.0.5

Also tested with Isar version 3.0.0/3.0.1
I think the issue is due to version compatibility of xcode in my pipeline and Isar, but I can't update Xcode version in my pipeline as it is increasing my app size.
Couldn't find compatible list of isar_flutter_libs & xcode version. Is there any ?

Kindly help

Comment: you can try downgrading ISAR even more.

Comment: I downgraded to 3.0.0 dev-08 and its working now but is it safe to use in production app, how stable is it, can there be issues in my app?

Comment: would recommend downgrading to stable versions only.